# Cyclic reference when adding EC2Service to Target Group by cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have this error below when adding `EC2Service` to `TargetGroup`

```
Error: 'dev-admin' depends on 'dev-alb' ({dev-admin/AdminService/Service}.addDependency({dev-alb/SharedListener/nginx-tg-add1/Resource}), {dev-admin/AdminService/Service}.addDependency({dev-alb/SharedListener/nginx-tg-add2/Resource}), dev-admin -> alb/nginx-tg/Resource.Ref). Adding this dependency (dev-alb -> dev-admin/ecs-admin-service-sg/Resource.GroupId) would create a cyclic reference.
```

My code is like this below,

in `dev-admin` make a `EC2service`

```
const ecsAdminService = new ecs.Ec2Service(this, 'AdminService', {
  cluster:props!.cluster,
  taskDefinition:adminTaskDefinition,
  serviceName: metaInfo['ecsServiceName']['admin'],
  enableExecuteCommand:true,
  securityGroups:[adminServiceSg],
  capacityProviderStrategies: [{
    capacityProvider: props!.adminCapacityProvider.capacityProviderName,
    base: 1,
    weight: 1,
  }],
})
this.ecsAdminService = ecsAdminService;
```

then pass the `EC2Service` object to `dev-alb` stack and then trying to add the `loadBalancerTarget` of 1Ec2Service`to`targetGroup`

```
  const securityGroup = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, "MyAlbSecGroup", "sg-079b53d9492xxxxxx")

  const listenerArn =   "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:6781002222222:listener/app/main-lb/a3de82872d7d166c/e247d72a4b0df559";
  const existingListener = elb.ApplicationListener.fromApplicationListenerAttributes(this, "SharedListener", {
    listenerArn,
    securityGroup
  });
  const targetGroupNginx = new elb.ApplicationTargetGroup(this,"nginx-tg", {
    port: 80,
    targets: [props!.ecsAdminService.loadBalancerTarget({ // I want to set the nginx-container to targets, but there comes cyclic reference.
      containerName: `nginx-container`,
      containerPort: 80,
    })],
    vpc: vpc,
  });
  existingListener.addTargetGroups("nginx-tg-add1",{
    priority:4,
    conditions:[
      elb.ListenerCondition.hostHeaders(['example.com'])
    ],
    targetGroups:[targetGroupNginx]
  })
```

Howevver it cause the cyclick reference.

What is the best practice to add the service to targetgroup?

Answer (score 0):

I think below piece of code adds a dependency of **dev-admin -> dev-alb** as per the documentation link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2-readme.html#using-a-load-balancer-from-a-different-stack

```
targets: [props!.ecsAdminService.loadBalancerTarget({ // I want to set the nginx-container to targets, but there comes cyclic reference.
      containerName: `nginx-container`,
      containerPort: 80,
```

And since we pass dev-admin service to dev-alb stack so we already have
**dev-alb -> dev-admin**

I guess that's why we are seeing circular references

May be you can refer to https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/cross-stack-load-balancer/split-at-targetgroup.ts guideline for splitting Target Groups and Alb in diff stack.